# How to Iterate the FilteredData and how to update in the UI using Redux with Typesecript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I got the State Data from Store. I created the Search Box to filter that Data, Now I got the FilterData also, But how I need to update my UI with that Filtered Data, In HandleSearch method I stored the the Filtered data in FilteredData varibale, But I am Unable to Iterate the FilteredData varibale and I am unable to update in the UI, BUt it is working in console, Now i need to update in the UI, Please can anyone help in this, Thanks in Advance...

```
        import { Dispatch } from "redux"
        import axios from 'axios'
        
        export const FETCH_SUCCESS : string ='FETCH_SUCCESS';
        export const FETCH_SEARCH  ='FETCH_SEARCH';
        
        export const fetchUser=()=>{
        
            return async (dispatch:Dispatch) =>{
                  try{
                    let dataUrl : string ="http://localhost:3000/users";
                    let response = await axios.get(dataUrl);
                     dispatch({type:FETCH_SUCCESS, payload : response.data})
                  } catch {
                      
                  }
                  
        
            }
        
        }
    
        import * as searchAction from './SearchAction';
        import {SearchingInter} from '../../componets/SearchingInter';
        
        export interface ISearch{
             search : SearchingInter[]
        }
        
        let initialSate : ISearch ={
            search : [] as SearchingInter[]
        }
        
        export const reducer =(state =initialSate , action:any) :ISearch =>{
        
            switch(action.type){
        
                case searchAction.FETCH_SUCCESS :
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        search : action.payload
                    };
        
     
                      default : return state;
            }
        
        
        }
    
    

import React, { ChangeEvent } from 'react';
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import {useSelector,useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import * as searchActions from '../Redux/SearchFetch/SearchAction';
import * as searchReducsers from '../Redux/SearchFetch/Searchreducer';
import SearchingData from './SearchingData';

 const Search = () => {

  let dispatch = useDispatch();

    let readingStateData : searchReducsers.ISearch = useSelector((state : {searchingData:searchReducsers.ISearch})=>{
                      return state.searchingData;
    })

   useEffect(() => {
       console.log(readingStateData.search)
      dispatch(searchActions.fetchUser());
    }, [])

     const handlesearching =(e:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
             //console.log(e.target.value);
             let defaultData = readingStateData.search;
             //console.log(defaultData);
            const filteredData = e.target.value ? defaultData.filter(user =>user.UserName.toLowerCase().startsWith(e.target.value)) : defaultData
           
     }

     

    return (
        <React.Fragment>

        <div className="container mt-3">
                      <div className="row">
                          <div className="col-md-3">
                              <div className="card">
                                 
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                            <SearchingData handleSearch={handlesearching}/>
                   
                      <table className="table table-hover text-center table-primary">
                          <thead className="text-black">
                          <tr>
                              <th>UserName</th>
                              <th>Phone</th>
                              <th>Email</th>
                              <th>Gender</th>
                          </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                              <React.Fragment>
                                  {
                                      readingStateData.search.map(user =>{
                                          return(
                                              <tr>
                                                  <td>{user.UserName}</td>
                                                  <td>{user.PhoneNumber}</td>
                                                  <td>{user.email}</td>
                                                  <td>{user.gender}</td>
                                              </tr>
                                          )
                                      })
                                  }
                              </React.Fragment>
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
                </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default Search;
```

import { type } from 'os';
import React, { ChangeEvent } from 'react'

```
    type searchData = {
        handleSearch : (e:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
    }
    
     const SearchingData:React.FC<searchData> = ({handleSearch}) => {
    
        const UpdateData =(e:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
            //console.log(e);
            handleSearch(e)
        }
    
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div>
                <input type="text"  onChange={UpdateData} />
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
    
    export default SearchingData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to have a state which will hold the filterData value. And set the initialValue of the state to the Data from the store

`const [ dataToDisplay, setDataToDisplay ] = useState(readingStateData?.search || [])`;

Add a second useEffect which looks for the change in the readingStateData?.search. Initially you have the search as [] but once there is data we need to sync that data with the components's internal state.

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(readingStateData?.search?.length > 0){
       setDataToDisplay(readingStateData?.search)
    }
}, [readingStateData?.search])
```

Now inside your `handleChange` you can update the state

```
const handlesearching =(e:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
            const newDataToDisplay =  e.target.value ? dataToDisplay.filter(user =>user.UserName.toLowerCase().startsWith(e.target.value)) : readingStateData?.search
            setDataToDisplay(newDataToDisplay);
     }
```

Now while rendering map over this `dataToDisplay` instead `readingStateData?.search`

```
dataToDisplay.map((user) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{user.UserName}</td>
      <td>{user.PhoneNumber}</td>
      <td>{user.email}</td>
      <td>{user.gender}</td>
    </tr>
  );
});
```

2. you can make your input as controlled input and have its value being read from the state

```
    const Search = () => {
      let dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      let readingStateData: searchReducsers.ISearch = useSelector(
        (state: {searchingData: searchReducsers.ISearch}) => {
          return state.searchingData;
        }
      );
    
      const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
    
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log(readingStateData.search);
        dispatch(searchActions.fetchUser());
      }, []);
    
      const handlesearching = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setSearchText(e.target.value);
      };
    
      const dataToDisplay = searchText.trim().length > 0
        ? readingStateData?.search.filter((user) =>
            user.UserName.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchText)
          )
        : readingStateData?.search;
    
      return (
              <React.Fragment>
                <SearchingData handleSearch={handlesearching} searchText={searchText} />
                {dataToDisplay.map((user) => {
                  return (
                    ....
                  );
                })}
              </React.Fragment>
      );
    };
    
    // In your Search Component add another prop called searchText
    
    type searchData = {
      handleSearch : (e:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
      searchText: string;
    }
    
    const SearchingData:React.FC<searchData> = ({handleSearch, searchText}) => {
    
      const UpdateData =(e:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
          //console.log(e);
          handleSearch(e)
      }
    
      return (
          <React.Fragment>
              <div>
              <input type="text" value={searchText} onChange={UpdateData} />
              </div>
          </React.Fragment>
      )
    }
    
    export default SearchingData
```

Comment: It is working But 1st time Data is not getting loaded when Page Loads.... data gets loaded only when I type anything in Searchbox... why it is like that?

Comment: Ah okay got it . you are making an api call to get the data . Have updated my answer .

Comment: But In useeEffect I need to dispatch an Action Right? Without Dispatch How I will update the data from Store... CAn you please check that once ?

Comment: This is a new useEffect which you need to add apart from the one you already have :-)

Comment: Yes It is working Perfectly, Thanks a lot @shyam .....But can you explain me why we need to take another UseEffect?? And is there any  another way to do?

Comment: Another approach will be to have your input value in state . Edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, Thank you @Shyam, I am new to Redux withn TS and I learned a new Thing today...
Once again thanks a lot for your patience  in answering the questions.. Thank you